# Android - library/app communication

Tags: java, android, events

I've worked with Android in the past, but haven't done anything super-advanced or what I'm about to describe so need some guidelines as to what the best approach/method is to do this before I proceed.

I'm not entirely sure how to google this, so it's best to explain.

I want to build an Android library project preferably with the source undisclosed. I read this can be done as follows: Create another jar that the Android library project references. However, not sure if all of the source code can be private. If anyone can point me somewhere, that would be great.

Asides from that, the library needs to expose an API for any Android app to use, and some sort of event mechanism to broadcast an event when certain events happen (e.g when the app is in foreground etc).

A scenario would be:

```
   1) User loads the app which has the library embedded

   2) The embedded library detects that the app has loaded and 'sends an event' to the app 

   3) The app captures the event and does some stuff specific to the app + an API call to the library
```

I guess what I'm interested mostly is figuring out what the best ways are to capture the callbacks by the app, once the library has sent some event to the app and to reduce the burden on the developer having to spend too much time implementing what needs to be done when certain events are captured.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You mean notifying another app? Because an app knows when it is put in background, when it's running, etc.

Comment: not another app. the library would be included in any app that would want to use it

Comment: So, you mean that an app embedding your library can be notified when another (unrelated) app is started, right?

Comment: no, is my description not clear enough?:( I mean the app embedding my library can capture events when the library broadcasts them.

Comment: I repeat: the app itself already has mechanisms to know when it's loaded, when it's put in the background and so on... I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that. I guess what I'm asking is what the best way is to handle events between an Android library and an app

Comment: Which approach did you take? Broadcasts? DataProvider? Your question should be paraphrased differently, without the number 2.